# Javascript alerts in Python + Selenium + PhantomJS script

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs

I try to "click" Javascript alert for reboot confirmation in DSL modem with a Python script as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import selenium
import time
from selenium import webdriver

cap = {u'acceptSslCerts': True,
u'applicationCacheEnabled': True,
u'browserConnectionEnabled': True,
u'browserName': u'phantomjs',
u'cssSelectorsEnabled': True,
u'databaseEnabled': False,
u'driverName': u'ghostdriver',
u'driverVersion': u'1.1.0',
u'handlesAlerts': True,
u'javascriptEnabled': True,
u'locationContextEnabled': False,
u'nativeEvents': True,
u'platform': u'linux-unknown-64bit',
u'proxy': {u'proxyType': u'direct'},
u'rotatable': False,
u'takesScreenshot': True,
u'version': u'1.9.8',
u'webStorageEnabled': False}


driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('/usr/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs', desired_capabilities=cap)
driver.get('http://username:passwd@192.168.1.254')
sbtn = driver.find_element_by_id('reboto_btn')
sbtn.click()
time.sleep(4)
al = driver.switch_to_alert()

print al.accept()
```

However, I get exception pasted below even though I do set `handlesAlerts` in `desired_capabilities`.

How can I fix that? What's the reason for the exception?

Exception:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/bin/pjs/asus_reboot.py in <module>()
36 #ipdb.set_trace()
37 
---> 38 print al.accept()
39 
40 #print al.text

/usr/local/venvs/asusreboot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/alert.pyc in accept(self)
76         Alert(driver).accept() # Confirm a alert dialog.
77         """
---> 78         self.driver.execute(Command.ACCEPT_ALERT)
79 
80     def send_keys(self, keysToSend):

/usr/local/venvs/asusreboot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.pyc in execute(self, driver_command, params)
173         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
174         if response:
--> 175             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
176             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
177                 response.get('value', None))

/usr/local/venvs/asusreboot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.pyc in check_response(self, response)
134             if exception_class == ErrorInResponseException:
135                 raise exception_class(response, value)
--> 136             raise exception_class(value)
137         message = ''
138         if 'message' in value:

WebDriverException: Message: Invalid Command Method - {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"53","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:36590","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"sessionId\": \"fc97c240-f098-11e4-ae53-e17f38effd6c\"}","url":"/accept_alert","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"accept_alert","directory":"/","path":"/accept_alert","relative":"/accept_alert","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/accept_alert","queryKey":{},"chunks":["accept_alert"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/fc97cea0-f098-11e4-ae53-e17f38eaad6c/accept_alert"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As PhantomJs has no support for Alert boxes .you need to use executor for this.

```
driver.execute_script("window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }");
```

Comment: can something similar be done for Javascript prompt textbox. @Innovation

Answer (score 1):

In java, driver.switchTo().alert().accept(); will do the job.

I am not sure, why you are using "print al.accept()", probably are you trying to print text?  then alert.getText() will do in java, sorry if i am wrong, because i am sure in python.

Thank You,
Murali
http://seleniumtrainer.com/

Comment: It does not work in 
Java for PhantomJs.
        Alert confirmationAlert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        String alertText = confirmationAlert.getText();